# Formulating Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

I am currently studying probability, and I've gotten pretty far (expectation conditioning, moment generating functions, etc.) and I can understand those concepts pretty well, but I am struggling with creating random variables. For example, I see a basic question like

`Consider n independent flips of a coin having probability p of landing heads. Say a changeover occurs whenever an outcome differs from the one preceding it. For instance, if the results of the flips are HHTHTHHT , then there are a total of five changeovers. If p = 1/2, what is the probability there are k changeovers?`

or

`Suppose that two teams are playing a series of games, each of which is independently won by team A with probability p and by team B with probability 1 − p. The winner of the series is the first team to win four games. Find the expected number of games that are played, and evaluate this quantity when p = 1/2`

and I have absolutely no idea how to formulate the random variables in order to begin solving the question.

I was working on exercises related to the higher level concepts, and I found that if the variables have already been formulated for me, or if it is was a question which does not require formulating of random variables, I have a much easier time solving them. I have tried to practice a bunch of questions, and currently I've reverted to much simpler questions (like the ones above) but it still does not make any sense. It always seems like there is a new trick to making the variables. Can anyone help me develop a better methodology for formulating random variables from questions?

To be clear, I am not looking for solutions to the specific questions above, but a better methodology to solve them.

Apologies if this question does not apply to this forum, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "formulating a random variable".  The first problem is a simple binomial process, yes?  The first toss can't be a changeover and, after that, each toss is a changeover with probability $\frac 12$ independent of all other tosses.

Comment: @lulu I want to know how I can better extract the information from a problem and turn it into a random variable that I can work with. I feel like after reading the solution, it all makes sense, but when I try to do it myself, it's completely incorrect.

Comment: Well...not sure where the problem is with that, at least in these two problems.  If you just want to get insight into a process, work it out for small cases.  For the first problem, just work out the cases for a small number of tosses.  For the second, try it for first team to win $2$ out of $3$.  Those cases are easy enough so that you can write everything out explicitly.

Comment: For a harder sort of exercise, use my hint to address the first problem for general $p$.  Of course the answer is more complicated in this case, as you need to keep track of which sort of changeover you have at any given moment.  That does not matter for the $\frac 12$ case.

Comment: @lulu I understand. However, I am having trouble abstracting this process to more complicated problems. In situations where I can't write out the smaller cases, or where there are compound variables... I end up going the wrong path.

Comment: I don't think there is a one-size-fits-all approach to these problems.  No magic bullet.  Just work more problems.  If nothing else, lots of problems resemble each other so the more examples you understand, the more new problems you can handle.

Comment: Should stress:  one of the great advantages of working special cases explicitly is that you can use those cases to test whatever theory you form for the general case. That is very important.